# Can "bring out" be used in the sense of "manufacturing", "make", or "build"?

Tags: word-usage

I've learnt that **"bring out"** means **"to produce, to publish something, especially a CD or a book"**. So how far can it stretch? Can it be used in the sense of **"manufacturing"**, **"make",** or **"build"**? Are the following examples natural?

1. The country brought out two million cars at the time.
2. The country brought out 4000 new buildings at the time.
3. The shop brought out 3 new types of cake at the time.

Comment: That's a *very* interesting definition of "bring out". I've never heard of that before. The meaning of "bring out" is usually to quite literally bring something out, but mostly in the context of intentionally showing off that thing to someone else. Where did you find that meaning from?

Comment: It's the last entry of this word in the OALD. Here's the [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bring-out?q=bring+out)

Comment: That definition is crude and misleading.

Comment: The definition is fine, it's just that the OP wants to use it for a completely different meaning. To publish a book is not the same as making cheese.

Comment: The definition is  "fine" in the sense of "OK" but not "fine" in the sense of "nuanced".

Comment: to bring out a *new product*. Any product.

Answer (score 3):

**bring out** can be used in a manufacturing context but it means "to introduce" as in a new model.

> The auto maker is bringing out a new small truck in 2026.

You wouldn't use it to refer to the actual production:

> The plant brought out 25,000 vehicles in three months time. <sup>not an idiomatic usage</sup>

You could say

> The publisher is bringing out six new sci-fi novels in the spring.

But again its meaning is "releasing, introducing to the market".

> The publisher brought out 100,000 copies of the novel in its first production run.  <sup>not an idiomatic usage</sup>

P.S. **put out** can be used for actual production

> This turbine puts out 25,000 kW per hour.

i.e. "generates"

as well as meanings closer to "releasing, publishing, bringing to the market"

> This new record label put out LPs that received six Grammy nominations in only two years time.

Comment: Thank you! What about "put out"? As I see in the OALD, "put out" has all the meanings you mentioned above.

Comment: For **put out** see the P.S.

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentences don't sound idiomatic, and wouldn't be used. In general, *bring out* is *not* a synonym for words, like "manufacture" or "build," which imply the construction of a *solid, physical structure*.

Your third sentence is perfectly valid, and one which is often used, but it has a different meaning from the one you've described.

> "The shop **brought out** 3 new types of cake at the time."

This actually means that the shop *already had the cakes before "the time"*, but *only then put them on display*. So, they "brought out" the cakes from *a literal place*, like a storage room or freezer. The sentence would not commonly be interpreted to mean the shop *began producing* the new types of cake at that time.

---

I'm not sure where you got the definition you cited, but personally I have never heard the phrasal verb "bring out" used in the sense you're asking about. Much more common would be to [**put out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putout) (specifically, as the *transitive* definitions **3** and **4**), which is used in contexts like the following:

> The studio **put out** 5 albums in the last month.

However, it can also have a vulgar meaning (as intransitive sense 3 in the linked dictionary), so you'll want to be sure that the idea you intend to express is clear from context!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the effort you put into this answer. For further discussion, here's the [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bring-out?q=bring+out) where I learned this sense of the word.

Comment: "The shop brought out three new cakes" could also mean that they started selling three new kinds of cake in addition to their existing range. The sense of 'bring out' is to produce something unique (like a book or recording), or something different from earlier ones.

Comment: 'Turn out' has a vulgar meaning too, I found as a youngster reading racy novels.